# Combining rows from one excel to another in a specific location

Tags: python, r, excel

I have 2 excel files with columns by the name of 
'State/Crop/District', 'Year', 'Season', 'Area (Hectare)', 'Production (Tonnes)', 'Yield (Tonnes/Hectare)'

In one excel file I have data for different states and under those states for different crops and under those crops for different district for 4 years.

In other file also, I have the same kind of data but only for one year.

I want to paste the data for that one year in 2nd file below the years for a particular district in the 1st file. I want to add year 2017-18 after the last year in the first file for a particular district.

Below is a sample of data I have in both excel files. 2nd file has data only for 2017-18 year. I have different states, one of which is "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", then the different crop names, one of which is "Arhar/Tur" and then different districts like "1.North....." and "2.South...."

```
State/Crop/
District    Year    Season  Area (Hectare)  Production         Yield 
                                                 (Tonnes)    (Tonnes/Hectare)

Andaman and Nicobar Islands                 
Arhar/Tur                   
 1.NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN  
         2013-14    Rabi        1   3   3.00
     2014-15    Rabi        13.9    14  0.99
     2015-16    Rabi        0.5 0   0.60
     2016-17    Rabi        6.5 0   0.05
 2.SOUTH ANDAMANS    
         2013-14    Rabi        0.5 0   0.40
     2014-15    Rabi        1   0   0.40
     2015-16    Rabi        0.5 0   0.40
```

Python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data1 = pd.read_excel('file:///C:/Users/3004/Desktop/AP.xls')
data2 = pd.read_excel('file:///C:/Users/3004/Desktop/States.xls')
result = pd.merge(data1,data2[['State/Crop/District','Year','Area (Hectare)','Production (Tonnes)'
                               ,'Yield (Tonnes/Hectare)',on='State/Crop/District',how='inner']])
```

I tried in R too,

```
vec<-c('Arhar/Tur','Wheat')
for (i in 1:length(vec)) 
  {if (AP$`State/Crop/District`==vec && AP$`State/Crop/District`==States$`State/Crop/District`)
  {rbind(AP$Year==2016-17,States$Year==2017-18)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `pd.concat` not a `pd.merge`:

- `pd.concat([data1, data2])` gives you a result similar to a SQL union.
- `data1.merge(data2, how='left')` gives you a result similar to a SQL left join.

Read the [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) for more info.